# expression failed to parse, unknown error

Tags: swift, xcode, runtime-error, closures, func

I am writing a function that takes two parameters, one integer and one closure. It calls the closure the integers value times.

This is my code

```
func repeatTask(times: Int, task: () -> Void) {
    for _ in 0 ..< times {
        task
    }
}

let voidClosure: () -> Void = {
    print("Swift Apprentice is awesome!")
}

repeatTask(times: 5, task: voidClosure)
```

The compiler gives me the following error:

> expression failed to parse, unknown error

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `()` after the `task`.

```
for _ in 0 ..< times {
    task()
}
```

Sometimes the compiler gives unhelpful errors, especially in Swift Playgrounds. In that case, I usually try an online sandbox like [this one](http://online.swiftplayground.run/).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just recognized that closures are the same like functions even in brackets